# How to make a shortcut for a template function instance in c++?

Tags: c++, function, templates, alias, using

I want to use `boost::math::binomial_coefficient<double>` in my module (cpp file). But instead of writing all that noise every time, I would like to assign it a simple name `binom`. But I struggle to find a decent way to do it.

`#define` for sure will do it, but it is recommended to avoid macros.

Wrapping it into my own function is an option too, but it's ugly, pollutes the header, and kinda defeats the purpose.

I hoped I could use a `using` to make a shortcut, but it doesn't compile:

```
using binom = boost::math::binomial_coefficient<double>;
// -> error: expected a type
```

I know I can use `typedef` to make aliases for template types (classes), but I don't see how to use that for a function.

I also tried assigning the function to a variable, but I get a warning:

```
auto binom = boost::math::binomial_coefficient<double>;
// -> warning: no previous extern declaration for non-static variable 'binom'
```

Comment: maybe `using binom = typename boost::math::binomial_coefficient<double>;` ?

Comment: Okay, that warning is odd. It's indicative of doing something fishy when declaring that variable. Can you post a [mre] please?

Comment: Is a typedef not an appropriate solution to this problem?

Comment: Assigning to variable should work. We need to see more code.

Comment: @IsaacCorbrey, no, it is not, since binomial_coefficient is not a type.

Comment: @Isaac, to alias a function? No

Comment: OH. That would explain the downvotes, I misread the question and thought that OP was trying to alias a type. Sorry about that lol

Comment: @max66 -> `error: typename specifier refers to a non-type template`

Comment: The last version where you assign to a variable should work. Please make a [mre].

Comment: @SergeyA @cigien adding `static` seems to remove the warning. If it works, I guess I write that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `auto`, use `const auto` or with recent compiler try `static constexpr auto` or `inline constexpr auto`.

Variable is still not good, as they remove overloads, default parameters, and may lead to unnecessary indirection.

Unfortunately, there isn't a good way, as far, as I know

```
using binom = boost::math::binomial_coefficient;
```

Is almost there, but it does not include `<double>`

Comment: adding any of `static`, `const` and `constexpr` removes the warning, thanks!